# Trying to implement a phpmailer into my project

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am new to php but I would like to use a phpmailer in my project. I have followed the steps from here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer but the form somehow does not send and I get a 404 problem. Can anyone help me understand what it is that I am doing wrong here?
My html file:

```html
<div class="container">
            <form method="POST" action="form.php"> 
                <div class="section7">
                    <div>
                    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Firma*" required><br>
                    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Nazwisko*" required><br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" required><br>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Wiadomość*" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input type="text" name="address_code" placeholder="Kod pocztowy*" required><br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Imię*" required><br>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Nr telefonu*" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="policy"></label><input type="checkbox" id="policy" name="policy" value="policy" required>
                    </label>Wyrażam zgodę na przetwarzanie moich <a href="#">danych osobowych</a> zgodnie z ustawą z dnia 29.08.1997 (Dz.U.nr 133,poz.883) o ich ochronie.</label><br>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Wyślij">
                </div>
            </form> 
            </div>
```

My php form file:

```js
<?php
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('mailer/class.smtp.php');
require_once('mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('phpmaileroauthgoogle.php');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $surname = $_POST['surname'];
  $company = $_POST['company'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $tel = $_POST['phone'];
  $address = $_POST['address_code'];
  $messageText = $_POST['message'];

  if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($tel) || empty($messageText) || empty($surname) || empty($company) || empty($address))  {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo json_encode("All fields are required.");
      exit;
  }

  $messageText .= "\nNumer telefonu: " . $tel;

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

  $mail->FromName = "$name";

  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
  $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
  $mail->Username = "myemail";
  $mail->Password = "mypassword";
  $mail->SetFrom("myemail");
  

  $mail->Subject = "Message sent from xxx website";
  $mail->Body = $messageText;
  $mail->AddAddress("myemail");
  $mail->AddReplyTo($email);


  if ($mail->send()) {
      echo json_encode("Thank you the message has been sent.");
  } else {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo json_encode("Sorry, there was an error");
  }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
   echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Comment: 404 means your URL is wrong. So maybe form.php isn't in the right place in your filesystem.

Comment: P.s. are you using JavaScript and AJAX to post the form? It isn't shown, but if you aren't, returning JSON from the PHP is a bit odd

Comment: I am not using JavaScript and AJAX

Comment: While you say you got your code from the right place on GitHub, somehow you've ended up with a really old version, and you've based your code on some random example rather than the ones supplied with PHPMailer, and you're doing some weird random things for no apparent reason (like setting `SMTPAutoTLS` when you're not using TLS mode). I recommend starting again using [the contact form example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

Comment: Is your form.php in the right place?

Comment: My php file is in the root folder

Comment: It needs to be in the same folder as the form

Comment: It is in the same folder as the form

Comment: Then, if the filename is also correct, there should be no reason it would return a 404 when submitting the form. Double-check your assumptions. Also pay attention to the comments above about why you are using an old version of the code and not a recent example from the website.